# How to get the outlook calendar dynamically in android application

Tags: android, calendar, outlook

I am developing an android application based on business Users,Hence i have to synchronize the user outlook calendar with my application calendar.Hence how can i do this function,Is there any link to refer,or is there any sdk available to synchronize.
Please help me,Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Outlook SDK Android: https://github.com/OfficeDev/Outlook-SDK-Android

Comment: Forget it, now it's broken due to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/active-directory-v2-preview-oidc-changes/